# Prolog: Create list containing elements at even indices

Tags: prolog

Basically, I need to write a predicate, `even_elts(L,M)`, such that `L` is a new list generated that contains only the even indexed elements from `M` (0th, 2nd, 4th, etc)

```
add_tail([X],[],X).
add_tail([H|NewT],[H|T],X) :-
   add_tail(NewT,T,X).

even_elts(L,[]) :- L = [].
even_elts(L,M) :- even_elts2(L,M,1).
even_elts2(L,[H2|T2],Ct) :-
   Ct2 is Ct + 1,
   ((Ct2 mod 2) =:= 0, add_tail(L,L2,H2), even_elts2(L2,T2,Ct2); even_elts2(L,T2,Ct2)).
even_elts2(_,[],_) :- !.
```

This works if `M` is empty or contains 1 or 2 elements. But, it only gets the first even indexed element from `M`, not the rest. Any pointers

EDIT: Solved the problem a different way, by removing the odd indexed elements rather than trying to create a new list and copying the data over. But, if someone can figure out a solution for my original code, I would be interested to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making this much more complicated than it is. You can use pattern matching to get each even element out, then collect those in the second (output) argument.

```
% an empty list does not have even elements
even_elts([], []).
% for all other lists, skip the second element (_),
% add the first to the output, recurse
even_elts([X, _ | L], [X | R]) :-
    even_elts(L, R).
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, never even thought of using the wildcard var to skip elements. Thanks!

Comment: Very nice, +1! In contrast to other solutions posted here, yours also works for the most general query `?- evens(Ls0, Ls).`.

Answer (score 2):

Just another approach with accumulator:

```
even_elts(L,M) :-
  even_elts(M,0,[],L).

even_elts([H|T],I,Acc,Ans) :-
  ( I mod 2 =:= 0, append(Acc,[H], AccNew)
  ; I mod 2 =:= 1, AccNew = Acc
  ),
  Inew is I + 1,
  even_elts(T,Inew,AccNew,Ans).

even_elts([],_,Acc,Acc).
```

And

```
?- even_elts(X,[1,2,3,4,5]).
X = [1, 3, 5] ;
```

Comment: while in general a valuable technique, calculating the mods - whose values we know in advance - for each sequentially increasing index, is a little bit too much. :)  But it is such a valuable technique in general.

Answer (score 0):

```
evens([A,B|C], [A|D]):- !, .....
evens(X, X).
```

is all you need. Fill in the blanks. :)

Comment: This will collect the odd elements.

Comment: Ah! Excuse me. That's a confusing exercise :)